# PostgreSQL UPDATE ignore placeholder

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a PostgreSQL construct to ignore an update on a specific column, while still using an assignment syntax ?

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn1 = 'myvalue1',
    mycolumn2 = IGNORE
```

Such an operation would only update `mycolumn1` and leave `mycolumn2` unchanged.

Comment: Don't add `mycolumn2 = IGNORE`

Comment: Just don't include the column in the `update`.  Why isn't that good enough?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd like to write a complete request with all the updates I want to be possible and do a simple text replacement with the values I provide, possibly incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `NULL` as param you could use:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn1 = 'myvalue1'
    ,mycolumn2 = COALESCE(param, mycolumn2)
```